# Format of converted Pdf is different from Word - Aspose.Words

Tags: aspose.words

I have a problem when saving Pdf document from Word document.

My code is as follows:

```
Aspose.Words.License licence = new Aspose.Words.License();
licence.SetLicense("Aspose.Total.lic");    
Aspose.Words.Document doc = new Aspose.Words.Document(@"C:\Users\martink\Desktop\slTest\slvesnik.docx");
doc.Save(@"C:\Users\martink\Desktop\slTest\slvesnik.pdf", SaveFormat.Pdf);
```

The problem is that the source and the destination documents are not the same.
The last lines of text from page 1 in Word are on page 2 in Pdf etc.

I'm giving you the source and the destination document in the attachment.

Thank you

[source document](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29461788/slvesnik.docx),
[destination document](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29461788/slvesnik.pdf)

Comment: I am Saqib, from Aspose. I noticed the same query in Aspose forums at http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/471680/problem-when-converting-pdf-from-word.aspx. The team is looking into this issue and will inform you as soon as it gets resolved.

Comment: Is it solved yet @SaqibRazzaq?

Comment: @ÖrjanJämte Sorry, the issue is not resolved yet.

Comment: Is it resolved yet @Saqib Razzaq

Comment: @Steve Yes, it was a very old issue and was fixed in Jun 2014. You may get in touch with support team if you need help.